# Why won't my module work even though I can import it?

Tags: python, c, linux, module, swig

I am following a tutorial from: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C I am referring to the section entitled "Using Swig". I create the files in his location:

```
~/Desktop/TEST2/helloMODULEtest
```

I first create a file called hellomodule.c with this code init:

```
/*hellomodule.c*/

    #include <stdio.h>

    void say_hello(const char* name) {
            printf("Hello %s!\n", name);
    }
```

I then create the file hello.i in the same location:

```
/*hello.i*/

%module hello
extern void say_hello(const char* name);
```

I have swig and python-dev installed on the Pi. So typing these three lines in the terminal:

```
$ swig -python hello.i
$ gcc -fpic -c hellomodule.c hello_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/
$ gcc -shared hellomodule.o hello_wrap.o -o _hello.so -lpython2.7
```

gives me these files:

- hellomodule.o
- hello.py
- _hello.so
- hello_wrap.c
- hello_wrap.o

I then sudo copy hello.py and _hello.so to my python2.7 lib file:

```
$ sudo cp ~/Desktop/TEST2/helloMODULEtest/hello.py /usr/lib/python2.7
$ sudo cp ~/Desktop/TEST2/helloMODULEtest/_hello.so /usr/lib/python2.7
```

After these steps I can the Python 2.7.9 shell. In the shell I type

```
 >>> import hello
```

and receive no warnings or errors, an indication that hello.py has been imported. But, when I type

```
>>> hello.say_hello("World")
```

The module appears to return nothing and goes to the next line. This is the "dialog" for the import and call to hello with the next entry line I have:

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.say_hello("World")
>>>
```

I would like to see this:

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.say_hello("World")
Hello World!
>>>
```

So, my question is why is nothing being returned from my hello.py module?

Comment: your function may print directly to system and `Python Shell` automatically prints vaules returned from functions. You need in `C` rather `return` instead of `printf()` to see result in `Python Shell`

Comment: try to run it directly in console - `python script.py` then maybe you will see your text in console.

Comment: Neither of the above suggestions work. If I try `>>> print hello.say_hello("World")` `None` is returned in where I'd like to see `Hello World!`. This was done with the code as it is in link [1].

Comment: `say_hello` doesn't return any value using `return` so python `print` will not work. As I sad `say_hello` uses `printf()` which probably sends text directly to system (Windows/Linux/Mac) and Python can't catch it. Put code in file and run file directly in console/terminal/cmd.exe/powershell so then maybe you will see your text.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `hello.i` file to this:

```
/*hello.i*/

%module hello
%{
void say_hello(const char* name);
%}

void say_hello(const char* name);
```